# WPA2-EAP & WPA3-EAP stopped working on Android 13 and above

Tags: android, wifimanager

If I'm posting in the wrong forum, please kindly point me to the right direction.

The same following codes worked for devices up to Android 12 has stopped working on 13 and above.

```
//partial environment settings
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
targetSdkVersion 28
```

```
//partial code
.....
val wifiManager =
applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

val enterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
enterpriseConfig.phase2Method = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2
enterpriseConfig.identity = "test"
enterpriseConfig.password = "123456"
val config = WifiConfiguration()
config.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\""
config.hiddenSSID = true

config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)

config.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig
val wcgID = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
Log.d("WIFI", "wcgID:$wcgID")
wifiManager.disconnect()
val b: Boolean = wifiManager.enableNetwork(wcgID, true)
wifiManager.saveConfiguration()
wifiManager.reconnect()
Log.d("WIFI", "b:$b")
...
```

Connection cannot be made successfully on Android 13+，with “val wcgID =
wifiManager.addNetwork(config);” it always gives you “-1”，devices on Android 12 and below all worked just fine.

Also, I found it works for connection types like PSK and WEP on Android 13+, just not EAP.

I tried to comment out the following lines, i.e. not configuring EAP and 802.1X:

```
//config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
//config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
```

When running "addNetwork", it doesn't give you "-1" anymore, but then it won't connect the target EAP-type SSID either.

I'm puzzled by this. Is it some configuration error or is Android 13+ simply doesn't support this method anymore? Are there better ways or workarounds to achieve this?

I would really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this!

Thanks in advance for your kindness and help!

Comment: Considering the UI changes when adding an EAP wpWifi may be the added config option on the certificate is the problem? BTW why is the Wifi hidden? A hidden Wifi AFAIK is bad for device privacy as the phone has to actively search for the WiFi. So for a secured Wifi I would not recommend to make it hidden.

Comment: @Conqueror din you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Nope. No solution yet. We are practically stuck. :-( If you guys have any thoughts, any thoughts at all, please share and we can explore together.